# OpenAM Web Agent Redirect Issue #403x

Tags: openam, opensso, forgerock

I am using OpenAM as an authentication solution for my web app. I have configured OpenAM behind a reverse proxy. I have made all the changes regarding headers and its working fine. I have also configured a site for the server. I can login as admin and configure realms and policies. I have configured a web agent to be used with my app. I am facing an issue with the web agent. When I login to my app request goes to OpenAM and it authenticates the user, but cannot redirect to the designated page. It just shows

`#403x`

on the browser. In the authenticator logs I see the following

```
amCDC:09/30/2021 01:54:19:020 PM UTC: Thread[http-apr-8080-exec-8,5,main]: TransactionId[786cdea2-e670-488d-955d-f6679002c3c0-1140]
ERROR: Invalid Agent: Could not get agent for the realm
java.lang.Exception: Goto URL not valid for the agent Provider ID
        at com.iplanet.services.cdc.LdapSPValidator.validateAndGetRestriction(LdapSPValidator.java:208)
        at com.iplanet.services.cdc.CDCServlet.redirectWithAuthNResponse(CDCServlet.java:375)
        at com.iplanet.services.cdc.CDCServlet.doGetPost(CDCServlet.java:343)
        at com.iplanet.services.cdc.CDCServlet.doGet(CDCServlet.java:234)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.forgerock.openam.validation.ResponseValidationFilter.doFilter(ResponseValidationFilter.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.forgerock.openam.audit.context.AuditContextFilter.doFilter(AuditContextFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2445)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

amCDC:09/30/2021 01:54:19:020 PM UTC: Thread[http-apr-8080-exec-8,5,main]: TransactionId[786cdea2-e670-488d-955d-f6679002c3c0-1140]
ERROR: CDCServlet.doGetPost
java.lang.Exception: Invalid Agent: Could not get agent for the realm
        at com.iplanet.services.cdc.LdapSPValidator.validateAndGetRestriction(LdapSPValidator.java:227)
        at com.iplanet.services.cdc.CDCServlet.redirectWithAuthNResponse(CDCServlet.java:375)
        at com.iplanet.services.cdc.CDCServlet.doGetPost(CDCServlet.java:343)
        at com.iplanet.services.cdc.CDCServlet.doGet(CDCServlet.java:234)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.forgerock.openam.validation.ResponseValidationFilter.doFilter(ResponseValidationFilter.java:44)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupFilter.doFilter(AMSetupFilter.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.forgerock.openam.audit.context.AuditContextFilter.doFilter(AuditContextFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2445)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have done all the relevant configuration for agent as well. I have disabled server lookup, set the following properties as recommended in documentation

```
com.sun.identity.agents.config.agenturi.prefix
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.protocol=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.host=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.port=true
```

My site url is

```
https://example.com/openam
```

I create the agent like this

```
server url = https://example.com:443/openam
agent url = https://example.com:443/
```

My Agent configurations is as follows

```
com.sun.identity.agents.config.agent.logout.url[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.agenturi.prefix=https://example.com:443/amagent
com.sun.identity.agents.config.anonymous.user.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.anonymous.user.id=anonymous
com.sun.identity.agents.config.attribute.multi.value.separator=|
com.sun.identity.agents.config.audit.accesstype=LOG_BOTH
com.sun.identity.agents.config.auth.connection.timeout=2
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.cdcservlet.url[0]=https://example.com:443/openam/cdcservlet
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.cookie.domain[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.change.notification.enable=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cleanup.interval=30
com.sun.identity.agents.config.client.ip.validation.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.convert.mbyte.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.name=iPlanetDirectoryPro
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.reset.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.reset[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.secure=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.debug.file.rotate=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.debug.file.size=10000000
com.sun.identity.agents.config.debug.level=All
com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.check.name.database=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.ltpa.config.name=LtpaToken
com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.ltpa.cookie.name=LtpaToken
com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.ltpa.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.encode.cookie.special.chars.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.encode.url.special.chars.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.fetch.from.root.resource=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.check.enable=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.default=example.com
com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.mapping[]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.get.client.host.name=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.path.info=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.path.info.for.not.enforced.list=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.preferred.naming.url=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.server.check=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.filter.priority=HIGH
com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.logonuser=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.owa.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.owa.enable.change.protocol=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.password.header=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.load.balancer.enable=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.local.log.rotate=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.local.log.size=52428800
com.sun.identity.agents.config.locale=en_US
com.sun.identity.agents.config.log.disposition=ALL
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url[0]=https://example.com:443/openam/UI/Login
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.cookie.reset[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.url[0]=https://example.com:443/openam/UI/Logout
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.ip[0]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.url.attributes.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.url.invert=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.url[0]=/logout.html
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.url[1]=/images/*
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.url[2]=/css/-*-
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.url[3]=/*.jsp?locale=*
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notification.enable=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.organization.name=/
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.host=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.notification.url=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.port=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.protocol=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.policy.cache.polling.interval=3
com.sun.identity.agents.config.policy.clock.skew=0
com.sun.identity.agents.config.poll.primary.server=5
com.sun.identity.agents.config.polling.interval=60
com.sun.identity.agents.config.postcache.entry.lifetime=10
com.sun.identity.agents.config.postdata.preserve.enable=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.cookie.maxage=300
com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.cookie.prefix=HTTP_
com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.fetch.mode=NONE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.mapping[]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.proxy.override.host.port=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.redirect.param=goto
com.sun.identity.agents.config.remote.log.interval=5
com.sun.identity.agents.config.remote.logfile=amAgent_xyz_com_443.log
com.sun.identity.agents.config.repository.location=centralized
com.sun.identity.agents.config.response.attribute.fetch.mode=NONE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.response.attribute.mapping[]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.session.attribute.fetch.mode=NONE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.session.attribute.mapping[]=
com.sun.identity.agents.config.sso.cache.polling.interval=3
com.sun.identity.agents.config.sso.only=false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.url.comparison.case.ignore=true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.userid.param=UserToken
com.sun.identity.agents.config.userid.param.type=session
com.sun.identity.client.notification.url=https://example.com:443/UpdateAgentCacheServlet?shortcircuit=false
org.forgerock.openam.agents.config.policy.evaluation.application=iPlanetAMWebAgentService
org.forgerock.openam.agents.config.policy.evaluation.realm=/
sunIdentityServerDeviceKeyValue[0]=agentRootURL=https://example.com:443/
sunIdentityServerDeviceStatus=Active
userpassword=
```

But still it is not working. Can someone explain what I am missing and how can I resolve this?

regards

**EDIT**

I have added headers to my nginx setup for the app

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forward-For op$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

now the error has changed

```
error:  [bq2ptiS62] Unknown issuer: http://example.com:8080/openam/cdcservlet Unknown issuer: http://example.com:8080/openam/cdcservlet {"stack":"Error: Unknown issuer: http://example.com:8080/openam/cdcservlet    
at PolicyAgent.<anonymous> (/node_modules/@forgerock/openam-agent/dist/policyagent/policy-agent.js:483:35)
at step (/node_modules/@forgerock/openam-agent/dist/policyagent/policy-agent.js:57:23)
at Object.next (/node_modules/@forgerock/openam-agent/dist/policyagent/policy-agent.js:38:53)
at fulfilled (/node_modules/@forgerock/openam-agent/dist/policyagent/policy-agent.js:29:58)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)","timestamp":"2021-10-04T15:21:40.630Z"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error repsonse body `#403x` is raised by OpenAM's CDCServlet when the value of the Agent profile property 'Agent Root URL' does not include the one sent with the CDSSO request.

Comment: can you elaborate? what configuration do I need to change to resolve this?
I encountered this link
https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-465

but cannot understand what I need to do.

Comment: Please provide the Agent profile as well as the HTTP request line to the CDCServlet and I will be able to exactly tell what needs to be done.

Comment: I have added agent config above, on node side I am creating Policy Agent like this

`var openamAgent = require('@forgerock/openam-agent');`
var CookieShield = openamAgent.CookieShield;`

`var agent = new openamAgent.PolicyAgent({`
`    serverUrl: "https://example.com:443/openam",`
`   appUrl: "https://example.com:443/",`
`    notificationRoute: '/',`
`    notificationsEnabled: true,`
`    username: 'newagent',`
`    password: "randstr",`
`    realm: '/',`
`    appName: 'iPlanetAMWebAgentService',`
`    logLevel: "info"})`

Comment: CDCServlet request line is

'https://example.com:443/openam/cdcservlet?TARGET=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fagent%2Fcdsso%3Fgoto%3D%252F&TARGET=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fagent%2Fcdsso%3Fgoto%3D%252F&RequestID=fMv7Nl8jp&MajorVersion=1&MinorVersion=0&ProviderID=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3A443%2F&IssueInstant=2021-10-04T15%3A21%3A02.976Z'

Comment: I have also updated the question.